# How to check if an image has previously been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where when the user clicks a link, the an image changes source. While the image loads, I have a loading spinner (I'm using a fontAwesome icon for it). Once the image finishes loading, some actions need to happen to hide the icon. I'm using the .load() event handler to do this actions once the image loads.

```
$('#targe img').load(function(){
    // Hide Loader / Show image
    $('#target img').removeClass('hide');
    $('#wb_noncanvas i').addClass('hide');
});
$('#targe img').attr('src','path/to/image.jpg');
```

This works as intended when the user clicks the link for the first time, but if they go to a different link and then go back to the first one, the event won't fire.

Comment: The non-JQuery way is like this: http://webtrick101.blogspot.com/2014/07/javascript-way-to-check-loaded-image.html (pure Javascript)